# Como identificar se usuário está digitando número ou caracteres?

Tags: c#

Tenho um textbox:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="buscador_GotFocus" Tap="buscador_Tap" KeyUp="buscador_KeyUp" TextChanged="buscador_TextChanged" Name="buscador" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="Teste"/>
```

Nele o usuário vai poder digitar qualquer tipo de caracter, porém quero tratar isso no código, pois tenho duas listas, uma com nome e outra com número. Então como saber se o usuário está digitando no textbox letra ou número? Usei if comparando o primeiro caracter só, mas depois do segundo caracter já não funciona..

Resumindo:

Quando o usuário digitar: `123` ele faz uma busca na lista de números.

Quando o usuário digitar: `abc` ele faz uma busca na lista de nomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui aqui implementando o seguinte método:

```
public bool VerificaString(string str)
{
    char[] c = str.ToCharArray();
    char le = ' ';
    for(int cont = 0; cont < c.Length; cont ++)
    {
        le = c[cont];
        if(char.IsLetter(le) || char.IsPunctuation(le))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1  Só pra comentar, uma alternativa seria `if(! char.IsDigit(le))`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 1):

Para identificar se o caractere  digitado é um número ou não você pode usar o TryParse do int.

```
int n;
bool ehUmNumero = int.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out n);
```

Comment: Para quem está procurando a melhor solução, é esta.

Answer (score 0):

Como não consigo comentar, portanto vou usar a resposta.
Espero que consiga te ajudar.

Tenho uma aplicação WP8, na qual precisei criticar a Placa Cavalo de um Caminhão, ou seja, tres letras e quatro números.

Depois de muito pesquisar consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

```
**<TextBox x:Name="txtCavalo" Canvas.Top="15" Canvas.Left="0" Width="180"  Text="" InputScope="Text" KeyDown="txtCavaloKeyDown" />**
```

Com o evento KeyDown é possível determinar individualmente a entrada, se a entrada está OK o `e.Handled = false`, para não aceitar a entrada faço o `e.handled=true`.

No evento KeyDown, está o seguinte código:

```
private void txtCavaloKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{           
    if (txtCavalo.Text.Length > 2)
    {
        if (txtCavalo.Text.Length < 7)
        {
            if ((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) | (e.Key == Key.Enter | e.Key == Key.Back | e.Key == Key.Shift))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Placa Cavalo - Informe 3 letras e 4 números.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Back | e.Key == Key.Shift | e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Placa Cavalo - Informe 3 letras e 4 números.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((e.Key == Key.A | e.Key == Key.B | e.Key == Key.C | e.Key == Key.D | e.Key == Key.E | e.Key == Key.F | e.Key == Key.G | e.Key == Key.H
        | e.Key == Key.I | e.Key == Key.J | e.Key == Key.K | e.Key == Key.L | e.Key == Key.M | e.Key == Key.N | e.Key == Key.O | e.Key == Key.P | e.Key == Key.Q
        | e.Key == Key.R | e.Key == Key.S | e.Key == Key.T | e.Key == Key.U | e.Key == Key.V | e.Key == Key.W | e.Key == Key.X | e.Key == Key.Y | e.Key == Key.Z)
        | (e.Key == Key.Enter | e.Key == Key.Back | e.Key == Key.Shift))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Placa Cavalo - Informe 3 letras e 4 números.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```